# invalid LOC header (bad signature) while downloading hamcrest-core-1.2.1.jar using maven install goal

Tags: maven, hamcrest

Error snippet : ".m2\repository\org\hamcrest\hamcrest-core\1.2.1\hamcrest-core-1.2.1.jar; invalid LOC header (bad signature)"

Invalid LOC header (bad signature) while downloading hamcrest-core-1.2.1.jar using maven install goal

Maven Dependency :

Tried :

```
"<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
  <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>"
```

and

```
"<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
  <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>"
```

getting same error in both the cases.

Comment: delete `.m2\repository\org\hamcrest\hamcrest-core\1.2.1\hamcrest-core-1.2.1.jar` to force maven to download it again. If still broken, then invalid file might be in repository which you are pulling from.Note `scope` has nothing to do with it, but unless you are building test library, your scope should be always `test` for hamcrest

Comment: The given answer of rkosegi is short solution. Please check your configuration https://blog.soebes.de/blog/2018/10/13/maven-artifact-checksums-what/ and furthermore check which kind of transfer you are using... https?